# ColorTween not working in TweenAnimationBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have tried the code referred in the flutter weekly widget https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9uHB8VXZOg. But Apparently I'm having issues with it.

```dart
TweenAnimationBuilder<Color>(
              tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.white, end: Colors.grey), // Having errors here
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              builder: (_, Color color, __) {
                return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      colorFilter: shouldChange
                          ? ColorFilter.mode(color, BlendMode.modulate)
                          : null,
                      image: AssetImage('assets/someasset.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: SomeWidgetHere...
                );
              },
            ),
```

It says that `The argument type 'ColorTween' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Tween<Color>'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)`

I have tried using the `Tween<Color>` but this is the error I face.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building
TweenAnimationBuilder<Color>(duration: 500ms, dirty,
dependencies: [_EffectiveTickerMode], state:
_TweenAnimationBuilderState<Color>#5bacf(ticker
active)):
Cannot lerp between "Color(0xffffffff)" and "MaterialColor(primary
value: Color(0xff9e9e9e))".
The type Color might not fully implement `+`, `-`, and/or `*`. See
"Types with special
considerations" at
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html for
more information.
To lerp colors, consider ColorTween instead.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  TweenAnimationBuilder<Color>
  SOME PATH HERE:29:20

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Tween.lerp.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/animation/tween.dart:268:9)
#1      Tween.lerp
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That tutorial is from the old days, when null-safety was not a standard :)

At the moment the source code for **ColorTween** states that both colors (begin and end) might be null and will be counted as transparent.

So the **ColorTween** has colors that might be null (that's **Color?** type).

To be able to use it with **TweenAnimationBuilder** - we have to tell this builder that the type used for the animation might be null.
We do this by defining **TweenAnimationBuilder<Color?>** instead of **TweenAnimationBuilder** as in your code above.

Also, we have to be sure that the **value** (second parameter) of the **builder()** function is null-safe too.

I've changed your code a bit to be able to run it locally, but you can just copy the changes near the comments.

```dart
TweenAnimationBuilder<Color?>( // <-- Color might be null
            tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.yellow, end: Colors.blue),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
            builder: (_, Color? color, __) { // <-- Color might be null
              return Container(
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                      color ?? Colors.transparent, // <-- If color is null - pass transparent
                      BlendMode.modulate,
                    ),
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7e/Dart-logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Container(),
              );
            },
          )
```

Comment: This was actually a significant update